# No entra a if, para comparar

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Tengo este codigo:

```
    if (parseInt(cantidad) === 0)
    {
        swal({
        title: "Su cantidad en stock es de 0 ",
        text: "Imposible agregar salida",
        icon: "warning",
        })
        .then((willDelete) => {
          if (willDelete) {

                }
                });
            }

            else if (parseInt(outSolicito) > parseInt(cantidad))
            {
                swal({
                title: "Imposible realizar registro de salida\n"+" "+"la cantidad ingresada de: "+" "+outSolicito+" "+"supera su cantidad actual en stock de:+"+cantidad+"",
                text: "Imposible agregar salida",
                icon: "warning",
                })
                .then((willDelete) => {
                    if (willDelete) {

                            }
                        });
            }

else{//hace el insert}
```

En el primer `if` estoy comparando `cantidad` `(en stock)` si esta esta en `ceros` entonces no podra registrar salida, en el siguiente `if`, pretendo si la `cantidad` que se esta solicitando es mayor a la cantidad actual en `stock` mande el mensaje `"la cantidad que solicito supera su`cantidad`en stock actual"`

El problema que tengo es que haciendo pruebas si  mi cantidad actual es de `100` e intento sacar `200` unidades, igual lo registra y obtengo números negativos, lo cual esta mal.

Ya intente poner el ese `if` dentro del primero, también fuera, pero no logro tener éxito.

Comment: El primer if funciona perfectamente, el problema es en el segundo, este no me deberia dejar registrar una salida de 200 unidades si actualmente tengo 100, es incorrecto, sin en cambio lo hace... no se donde poner ese if o hacer la comparacion de otra manera.

Comment: parcticamente lo que estas comparando es `parseInt("200") > parseInt("100")`, si es asi deberia de mandar la notificacion. Ademas `outSolicito` y `cantidad` son cadenas?, estas seguro que esos son los valores que contiene?

Comment: ya imprimiste a consola `parseInt(outSolicito)` y  `parseInt(cantidad)`?

Comment: quizás el problema es que no esta entrando a la `successcallback` porque la funcion swal ejecuta error en vez de success

Answer (score 1):

Es posible que tu error esté en otro momento de ejecución, tu código funciona bien.

He cambiado tu código con la misma lógica, ojalá te ayude a entender mejor.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    guardarPedido(200);
});

function guardarPedido(cantidadPedido) {
    const validador = validarCantidad(cantidadPedido);
    if (validador.isValid) {
        alert('Enviar datos al servidor');
    } else {
        swal(validador.swalData);
    }

}

function validarCantidad(cantidadPedido) {
    var stock = 100;
    const swalData = { title: "", text: "Imposible agregar salida", icon: "warning" };

    if (parseInt(stock) === 0) {
        swalData.title = "Su cantidad en stock es de 0 ";
        return { "isValid": false, swalData: swalData };
    }

    if (cantidadPedido > stock) {
        swalData.title = `Imposible realizar registro de salida\n la cantidad ingresada de:  ${cantidadPedido} supera su cantidad actual en stock de:+ ${stock}`;
        return { "isValid": false, swalData: swalData };
    }


    return { "isValid": true, swalData: swalData };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn"> Pedir 200 productos </button>
```